# Como usar dois atributos CSS ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: html, css

O código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 style="color:#CC0099">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Vêem esse `<h1>`? Ele tem uma propriedade `style=""`, isso eu consegui implementar com sucesso, mas não sei como faço pra adicionar a fonte *Verdana* no mesmo `<h1>` sem alterar a cor.

Comment: Tanto de resposta eu acho impossível você ficar sem aprender agora. Abraço :-)

Comment: Só faltou marcar alguma pergunta como resolvido

Answer (score 18):

Você pode usar `;` e `font-family`, como já citado pelos demais usuários, um exemplo:

```html
<h1 style="color:#CC0099; font-family: Verdana">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

No entanto para uma melhor organização recomendo usar arquivos CSS, folhas de estilo.

Por exemplo, crie um arquivo chamado `estilo.css` e adicione isto a ele:

```
.titulo1 {
   color: #CC0099;
   font-family: Verdana;
}

p {
    color: red;
}
```

No html chame-o assim (o css deve estar na mesma pasta que o seu html e o `<link>` deve ficar dentro de `<head>`):

Exemplo no html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="titulo">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Você também pode dividir por "divs", por exemplo:

estilo.css:

```
.box1 h1 {
   color: #CC0099;
   font-family: Verdana;
}

.box1 p {
    color: red;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <h1 class="titulo">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O seletor `.box1 h1` vai aplicar o estilo a todos elementos `h1` dentro de elementos que tiverem a classe `box1`.

Recomendo que leia:

- http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php
- http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/insetut.php
- http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/intrtut.php
- http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/faq.php

Answer (score 4):

Deve ter errado na sintaxe, como você não mostrou como fez, não posso apontar o erro exato. Veja funcionando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 style="color:#CC0099; font-family:Verdana">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/TwoAttributes.html).

Não sei se usou a propriedade certa, se esqueceu o `;` ou tentou aplcia dois `style` separados.

Tem diversas formas de fazer isto. Esta é uma sintaxe válida embutindo o CSS no HTML. Para testar é prático mas se recomenda separar os estilos sempre que possível.

Comment: O que será que tem de errado na minha resposta pra merecer um negativo?

Answer (score 3):

Creio que deseja fazer isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 style="color:#CC0099; font-family:verdana;">Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Contudo, recomendo estudar um pouco de [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS). Em geral, a aplicação de estilos nas páginas é sempre feita usando esta linguagem de estilo e não usando diretamente o atributo `style`, como fez. Veja um exemplo de como poderia ficar utilizando CSS sem `style`: https://jsfiddle.net/7o40548b/1/

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Um dia eu aprendo</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1{
  color:#CC0099; 
  font-family: Verdana;
}

p{
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um `;` e colocar o atributo seguinte, porém, não é recomendado colocar os estilos dentro da própria tag. Como já citaram, coloque dentro das tags `<style>/*Estilos CSS*/</style>`

Answer (score -1):

basta adicionar ; font-family: Verdana apos o código da cor!